# Python3 append value to array but only if it's not None

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I got function that it's searching for something, and may not return anything.
I want to append it to array but only if it return something

pseudocode

```
def fu():
    if sometring:
        return result

a = []
a.append(fu())
```

now if this function doesn't return value it appends "None" to array `[result1, None, result2,etc]`, how to avoid that?

Comment: `ret = fu()` `if ret is not None: a.append(ret)`?

Comment: In Python every function returns something. If you don't specify what to return, it will return `None`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A function automatically returns `None` if you don't have a return statement. To avoid appending `None` to a list, check it before appending.

```
result = f()
if result:
    a.append(result)
```

Or use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out `None` in the end.

```
a = [1, 2, None, 3]
a = filter(None, a)

print(a)
# Output
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Though, the second case is horrible if you call function enormous number of times and it supposed to return value very seldom.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew the `None` operation of `filter`, I always thought the first argument had to be a function.

Comment: For complement, according to the doc, `filter(None, iterable)` will also filter 0, empty string and any `bool(obj)` which is `False`, which may or may not be the desired behavior.